# Why is this code resolved to true?

Tags: c

```
int main() {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 0;

    if (a = b || ++a == 2)
        printf("T: a=%i, b=%i", a, b);
    else
        printf("F: a=%i, b=%i", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

Let's take a look at this simple code snippet. Result is: **T: a=1, b=0**

Why? (note `a=b` uses assignment operand, not comparison)

What I understand here, is that **zero** is assigned to **a**, then **a** is incremented to 1. 1 is not equal to 2. So result should indeed be **a=1, b=0**. But why is this condition evaluated to true? Neither of `(a=b)` or `(++a == 2)` is true ... What did I miss?

Here is other short program that prints **F** as expected:

```
int main() {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 0;

    if (a = b) printf("T"); else printf("F");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you switch your || conditions it would probably evaluate to false as you expect.

Comment: Oh, sorry it's not a duplicate.  My mistake.

Comment: @M.Babcock yes, it does but why this doesn't?

Comment: @Oli: `||` is a sequence point.

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche: Indeed, but not where it matters.

Comment: @Oli: Yes, but it's not a duplicate, even if related (i.e. without the precedence problem being pointed out, the sequence points are meaningless here).

Comment: It's very hard to find similar question like this just by stackoverflow search. It might seem similar but I didn't know how to find something similar, it is too specific I guess.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have confused yourself with misleading spacing.

```
if (a = b || ++a == 2)
```

is the same as:

```
if (a = (b || ((++a) == 2)))
```

This actually has undefined behavior. Although there is a sequence point between the evaluation of `b` and the evaluation of `((++a) == 2)`, there is no sequence point between the implied assignment to `a` and the other write to `a` due to the explicit `=` assignment.

Comment: For extra credit, once you know it is supposed to be parsed like this, is it defined, what with `a` being assigned and auto-incremented?

Comment: @Complicatedseebio: I'm not sure what you are asking for that isn't in my answer.

Comment: @CharlesBailey Sorry, I didn't see it the first time. Yes, that answers my question.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, assignment has the lowest operator precedence so your if statement is equivalent to:

```
if ( a = ( b || ( ++a == 2 ) ) )
```

So you're assigning a to 1 but also incrementing it in the same expression.  I think that leads to undefined behavior, but the end result is that a is 1 in your compiler.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GCC or another compiler with similarly useful warnings, turning warnings on would give you a very large hint as to what's gone wrong here.  With `gcc -Wall`:

> warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value

To be precise: the compiler is interpreting the code as `if (a = (b || ++a == 2))`, and the warning is suggesting that you write it as `if ((a = (b || ++a == 2)))` to emphasize that the code is as intended, not a typo for the more common `if (a == (b || ++a == 2))`.

So the warning requires a bit of interpretation.  To get your desired effect, coincidentally enough you need to add parentheses around a *different* assignment used as a truth value, namely `(a = b)`.  Nonetheless the warning tells you that something is untoward about this particular line of code and that it deserves further scrutiny.

Comment: With recent GCC, there's also a warning about the resulting sequence point-related undefined behaviour.  This is another large red flag, as in the intended parsing there are clearly no sequence point issues.